# ddd+ubuntu+gnuplot error

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

Just started using ddd with ubuntu. I'm able to do the basic operations(step and watch) without any problems.

But, when I try to view a graph, it gets stuck on the "Starting gnuplot" screen.

when I cancel the dialog box, ddd exits with the following error message:

```
Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 154941792

(Annoyed?  Try 'Edit->Preferences->General->Suppress X Warnings'!)
Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 153210976

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 154944592

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 154943384

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 154999536

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 154998648

X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  10 (X_UnmapWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  16950
  Current serial number in output stream:  16953
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  10 (X_UnmapWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  16952
  Current serial number in output stream:  17116

X error (invalid Window parameter).

Oops!  You have found a bug in DDD.

If you can reproduce this bug, please send a bug report
to <ddd@gnu.org>, giving a subject like

    DDD 3.3.11 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) gets `BadWindow' error

To enable us to fix the bug, you should include the following information:
* What you were doing to get this message.  Report all the facts.
* The contents of the `~/.ddd/log' file as generated by this session.
Please read also the section "Reporting Bugs" in the DDD manual.

We thank you for your support.
```

the code i am using for testing this is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int a[10];
 for(int z=0;z<=10;z++)
 {
  a[z]=z;
  cout<<z;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

using ubuntu 10.04
have installed gnuplot from

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

Comment: What is the problem are you experiencing? Please do what it asks you to do.

Answer (score 2):

- Turn off X-Windows warnings
- Report this as a bug to ddd@gnu.org. Give them everything needed to reproduce it.

Comment: I was wondering if this was an error with my configuration, or is it really a bug..  If i search for the error message, i get quite a few links to unsolved problems, but couldnt find a solution.  will still submit it though